# Virsh error, Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory

Tags: qemu, linux-kvm, libvirt, virsh

I am trying to setup KVM, but when running certain wirsh commands like:
`$ sudo virsh net-define br10.xml`  or `$ sudo virsh pool-define-as debian_pool dir - - - - "/home/$USER/VM"`
I get this:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor

error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

When jumping into virt-manager GUI a get this dialog Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.

And when running virsh list I get empty table

```
 Id   Name   State
--------------------
```

I checked if I am in both kvm and libvirt groups and that seems okey. I also checked if the libvrt-sock file is created when running `$ sudo systemctl start libvirtd.service` but there is nothing.

I could use a little help here fellas and I'll be thankfull for any suggestions :3 .